# Js group items with common keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to make sure that by specifying the keys, objects that have the following keys in common are put in the same same array position.

I did it this way, but I wanted to know if there is a better way.

I don't really like using the map.

```js
let a = [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "boat": {
          "licensePlate": "AR002",
        },
        "from": "2020-06-20T16:09:00.000Z",
        "to": "2020-06-23T16:09:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "boat": {
          "licensePlate": "AZ001",
        },
        "from": "2020-06-19T22:00:00.000Z",
        "to": "2020-06-22T21:59:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "boat": {
          "licensePlate": "AR002",
        },
        "from": "2020-06-20T16:09:00.000Z",
        "to": "2020-06-23T16:09:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "boat": {
          "licensePlate": "AZ001",
        },
        "from": "2020-06-20T18:00:00.000Z",
        "to": "2020-06-21T18:00:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "boat": {
          "licensePlate": "AZ001",
        },
        "from": "2020-06-19T22:00:00.000Z",
        "to": "2020-06-22T21:59:00.000Z",
      }
    ];

function groupBy(list, keyGetter) {
        const map = new Map();
        list.map((item) => {
             const key = keyGetter(item).join(",");
             const collection = map.get(key);      
             if (!collection) map.set(key, [item]);
             else collection.push(item);
        });
        return map;
    }
    
    const grouped = groupBy(a, c => [c.boat.licensePlate, c.from, c.to]);
    
    const events = Array.from(grouped, ([id, ev]) => ({
     id,
     title: ev[0].boat.licensePlate,
     allDay: false,
     start: new Date(ev[0].from),
     end: new Date(ev[0].to)
    }))

console.log(events);
```

Result by grouped:

```
  let a = [
  [{
    "id": "1",
    "boat": {
      "licensePlate": "AR002",
    },
    "from": "2020-06-20T16:09:00.000Z",
    "to": "2020-06-23T16:09:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "boat": {
      "licensePlate": "AR002",
    },
    "from": "2020-06-20T16:09:00.000Z",
    "to": "2020-06-23T16:09:00.000Z",
  }],
  [{
    "id": "3",
    "boat": {
      "licensePlate": "AZ001",
    },
    "from": "2020-06-20T18:00:00.000Z",
    "to": "2020-06-21T18:00:00.000Z",
  }],
  [{
    "id": "4",
    "boat": {
      "licensePlate": "AZ001",
    },
    "from": "2020-06-19T22:00:00.000Z",
    "to": "2020-06-22T21:59:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "boat": {
      "licensePlate": "AZ001",
    },
    "from": "2020-06-19T22:00:00.000Z",
    "to": "2020-06-22T21:59:00.000Z",
  }]
];
```

Comment: `list.map()` isn't assigned anywhere so it should be `list.forEach()`. Anyway, probably a better question for [codereview.se].

Comment: Please be specific: are you trying to put objects with the same license plate into arrays, so each array contains entries with the same license plate? What have you tried? What's the specific problem you're having a problem with?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `reduce` here, I suppose this is what you need:

```js
var a = [ { "id": "1", "boat": { "licensePlate": "AR002", }, "from": "2020-06-20T16:09:00.000Z", "to": "2020-06-23T16:09:00.000Z", }, { "id": "5", "boat": { "licensePlate": "AZ001", }, "from": "2020-06-19T22:00:00.000Z", "to": "2020-06-22T21:59:00.000Z", }, { "id": "2", "boat": { "licensePlate": "AR002", }, "from": "2020-06-20T16:09:00.000Z", "to": "2020-06-23T16:09:00.000Z", }, { "id": "3", "boat": { "licensePlate": "AZ001", }, "from": "2020-06-20T18:00:00.000Z", "to": "2020-06-21T18:00:00.000Z", }, { "id": "4", "boat": { "licensePlate": "AZ001", }, "from": "2020-06-19T22:00:00.000Z", "to": "2020-06-22T21:59:00.000Z", } ];

var result = Object.values(a.reduce((acc,{id, boat, ...rest})=>{
   const key = [...Object.values(rest), boat.licenseplate].join('|');
   acc[key]=[...(acc[key] || []), {id, boat, ...rest}];
   return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `reduce` as mentioned in the other answer.

With this approach, you can remove 'duplicates' by 'iterating over `a`' one time to generate the new unique id by combining the `'${ licensePlate},${from},${to}'`  .

```js
const a = [{
  "id": "1",
  "boat": { "licensePlate": "AR002" },
  "from": "2020-06-20T16:09:00.000Z",
  "to": "2020-06-23T16:09:00.000Z",
}, {
  "id": "5",
  "boat": { "licensePlate": "AZ001" },
  "from": "2020-06-19T22:00:00.000Z",
  "to": "2020-06-22T21:59:00.000Z",
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "boat": { "licensePlate": "AR002" },
  "from": "2020-06-20T16:09:00.000Z",
  "to": "2020-06-23T16:09:00.000Z",
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "boat": { "licensePlate": "AZ001" },
  "from": "2020-06-20T18:00:00.000Z",
  "to": "2020-06-21T18:00:00.000Z",
}, {
  "id": "4",
  "boat": { "licensePlate": "AZ001" },
  "from": "2020-06-19T22:00:00.000Z",
  "to": "2020-06-22T21:59:00.000Z",
}];

function getUniqueObjects(input) {
  return Object.values(input.reduce((updatedList, {
    id,
    boat: {
      licensePlate
    },
    ...rest
  }) => {
    const newId = `${licensePlate},${rest.from},${rest.to}`;
    if (!updatedList[newId]) {
      updatedList[newId] = {
        id: newId,
        title: licensePlate,
        allDay: false,
        start: new Date(rest.from),
        end: new Date(rest.to),
      }
    }

    return updatedList;
  }, {}));
}

console.log(getUniqueObjects(a));
```